# Spring Boot - MVC - RestTemplate: Where to initialize a RestTemplate for a MVC application to consume remote RESTful services

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am going to develop a simple Spring MVC web application that will consume a remote RESTful service sitting on Heroku.

I would like the MVC web application to call the REST service as per controller. E.g.

- `localhost:8080/items` to call `http://{REMOTE_SERVER}/api/items`
- `localhost:8080/users` to call `http://{REMOTE_SERVER}/api/users`

etc, etc.

I have followed the Spring's official Spring Boot documentation ["Serving Web Content with Spring MVC"](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) to create a Hello World application with a `GreetingController` for an example. I would like to take advantage of Spring's RestTemplate to call the REST services.

My Application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

    }
}
```

My GreetingController:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {
    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(name = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name,
            Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "greeting";
    }
}
```

How and where will I need to initialize RestTemplate, making a Singleton class the `main` function of the Application class and allowing it to be shared by multiple controllers, or one per controller? What is the best practise to accomplish such a task?

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the [official documentation](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/).
Indeed you may reuse the template and instantiate it once by publishing it as a `@Bean` in your main configuration class (in your case `@SpringBootApplication`)

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    return builder.build();
}
```

and get it injected into the `GreetingController` by autowiring it as a property (or by constructor injection):

```
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

Of course you may also inject the `RestTemplateBuilder` and call `build` locally in your controller, if you want to customize it.

```
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
public GreetingController(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    this.restTemplate = builder.build(); // modify it before building
}
```

Comment: If you decide to publish your RestTemplates as a beans in your configuration class, you may want to qualify them by adding a name to them (`@Bean("items-service")`) and using `@Qualifier("items-service")` when injecting them.

Answer (score 1):

Its simple.

You just need to create a `new` RestTemplate and use it.
Better way is to have an application level RestTemplate managed by spring context.
Add below factory method to your @Configuration file

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate myRestTemplate() {
  return new RestTemplate();
}
```

*Using it:*

```
public MyClass{
  @Autowired
  RestTemplate myRestTemplate;

  public void myMethod(){
    // use rest template
  }
}
```

---

**Singleton or One per Host**

From Spring Docs

> RestTemplate
>
> The RestTemplate is the central Spring class for client-side HTTP
>   access. Conceptually, it is very similar to the JdbcTemplate,
>   JmsTemplate, and the various other templates found in the Spring
>   Framework and other portfolio projects. This means, for instance, that
>   the RestTemplate is thread-safe once constructed, and that you can use
>   callbacks to customize its operations.

Hence you can create your RestTemplate its safe to share with multiple threads invoking a REST call simultaneously with different hosts.

Ref: https://spring.io/blog/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate

Comment: Where should the myRestTemplate() method go to? The `main` function of the `Application` class?

Comment: Yes. Another way is to have a separate class marked as @Configuration to have all you app level configurations